# PDFs don't appear in RoxyFileManager

Tags: php, roxy-fileman

Has anyone had this issue before?

I am using Roxy File Manager on a site, and it works great, but for some reason won't display PDFs in the file browser.

I can upload them just fine (checked through FTP), but the file manager just doesn't seem to show them.

Comment: Are you using "insert/edit link" rather than "insert/edit image". PDFs should show for links.

Comment: Perfect, that works! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zef commented, PDFs will appear if clicking the "insert/edit link" rather than "insert/edit image"